# Why dart type system does not complain when fed () => String instead of () => void?

Tags: dart

This is definitely not a critical question, but still I am wondering why would this compile and work:

```
String stringReturningHandler() {
  print("clicked");
  return 'crash';
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: OutlineButton(
            child: Text('Click me'),
            onPressed: stringReturningHandler,
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Taking into consideration that `OutlineButton` defines `onPressed` as:
`@required VoidCallback onPressed,`

and `typedef VoidCallback = void Function();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a language like C, a `void` function is a procedure, it doesn't return anything, and it's different from non-`void` functions. Not so in Dart.

All functions in Dart return a value, even a `void` function. That's one of the consequences of having dynamic invocation:

```
dynamic something = print;
dynamic result = something("else");
```

This code should run successfully, so the result of calling `something`, which is actually the `print` function with signature `void Function(String)`, must be a value. We don't know which, but it must be *something*. (In practice it's `null`).

Also, because Dart has generics, and you sometimes want to abstract over the return type, `void` is treated like a proper type everywhere, which is what allows `Future<void>`. A future *is* an abstraction over the result of a computation - a return value.

Because of that, the type `void Function()` is not completely distinct from `String Function()`. The meaning of `void Function()` is "a function which returns a value that you must not use". Or, in other words, "a function where nobody cares what it returns" (because nobody will use it).

In Dart, the type `String Function()` is a subtype of `void Function()`. You can use a function returning a string in a place where nobody cares what is returned.
That's why nobody complains that `stringReturningHandler` is used where a function taking zero arguments is required, and where nobody cares what it returns.

Dart has always *allowed* you to override a `void` returning function with a non-`void` returning function in a subclass, which is another way to see that the non-`void`-returning function is a subtype.

Comment: My background is from Scala where everything is a bit more strict. So when I noticed this it felt a bit weird.
Thanks for the answer. I think this is part of the language design and related to having `dynamic noSuchMethod` in the top level `Object` class.

Comment: Could you maybe point to an example of where such dynamic invocations are really useful or where there are no alternatives to using them?

Comment: Dynamic invocations are rarely *necessary*, but when they are, it's because the user knows things about the relations of objects that cannot be captured in the type system. For example, the if you know that you have a function taking one argument, and one value which is a valid argument, but you don't actually know the type of the argument at compile-time, then you can still do `Function f = the Function; return f(theArgument);` (where `Function` is like `dynamic`, but only for function calls). In many cases, you can get around this, but for the tricky edge cases, you can fall back on dynamic.